# How can I modify my jQuery to update html on a toggle button that is activated differently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, toggle

I have jQuery sliding divs on a page that are toggled using a button on each slider. When the button is clicked, the content slides down and the text on the button is changed from "View More" to "Close". When the button is clicked again, the content slides back up and the text on the button is changed back to "View More". The jQuery I posted below works for this functionality.

I want to now have one of the sliders slide down automatically when there's a hash tag in the url. I got this working with the code below. The text on the trigger button is changed during this auto slide to "Close", which is what I want, but when I click the button to slide up, the text isn't changed back to "View More". Then when I click the toggle button it starts changing the text on the button again, but this time it's starting from "Close" instead of "View More" so it's opposite of what it should be because of the previous change. Did that make any sense? haha.

Any ideas how I can setup my jQuery so when I click the "Close" button after the hash auto-open it will change the text to "View More"? Thanks for any help

```
    <script language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#toggleButton1').click(function() {$('#toggleSection{row_count}').slideToggle('slow', function() {
         // Animation complete.
            });
        });
            $('#toggleButton1').toggle(
                function() {$('#toggleButton1').html('Close');
            },
                function() {$('#toggleButton1').html('View More');
           });

        {/facility_sections}
        {/exp:channel:entries}

        if (window.location.hash) {
            $('#toggleSection1').slideToggle('slow');
            $('#toggleButton1').html('Close');}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you change the text on the click button ?
you can add this code to you click function

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#toggleButton1').click(function() {

           var buttonValue = $(this).val();
           switch(buttonValue)
           {
             case 'Close':
              buttonValue = 'View More';
              $('#toggleSection1').hide('slow');
              $('#toggleSection2').show('slow');
              break;
             case 'View More':
              $('#toggleSection1').show('slow');
              $('#toggleSection2').hide('slow');
              buttonValue = 'Close';
              break;
          }
          $(this).val(buttonValue);
   });
});
```

here is the html:

```
<div id='toggleSection1' style='display:none'>toggle section 1</div>
<div id='toggleSection2' style='display:none'>toggle section 2</div>

<input type='button' id='toggleButton1' value='View More' />​
```

another option is to have a Boolean value that will indicate if it is close or not
so just declare the variable where you will have access to

```
var isClose = false;
```

here is a simple code that you can take a look
http://jsfiddle.net/2R9yE/11/

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll have to modify this a bit, but it should do the trick!